# Elastic Beanstalk suddenly stopped connecting to RDS database?

Tags: mysql, amazon-rds, elastic-beanstalk

I have a Flask app that I'm deploying with Elastic Beanstalk. It connects to an RDS database running MySQL. I can connect to it just fine from my computer or through SSHing to the EC2 instance and connecting from there. However, accessing the site gives a 502 error, and [this](https://gist.github.com/jaredgoodman03/5d9328fb26e527d17d2be48fcb815376) is the log, saying that it can't connect. What's going on?